# how can I dynamically allocate a number of datagridview in tablelayout?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want dynamic allocation datagridview in tablelayout.

For example, I choose number of grids, (2, 4, 9, 16...)

next, create this number of datagridview controls and place them in tablelayout.

Example:

[image]

So, how can I allocate dynamically allocate a number of Datagridview using one tablelayout

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created new Form (`Form1`), added new `TableLayoutPanel` with name `t` and added this code for form contructor:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    int row = 1; // number of rows
    int col = 2; // number of columns (change them to see effect)
    var grids = new DataGridView[row,col];

    // create rows and set their height
    t.RowCount = row;            
    t.RowStyles.Clear();
    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
    {
        var style = new RowStyle();
        style.SizeType = SizeType.Percent;
        style.Height =(float)(1.0/row);
        t.RowStyles.Add(style);
    }

    // create columns and set their width
    t.ColumnCount = col;
    t.ColumnStyles.Clear();
    for (int c = 0; c < col; c++)
    {
        var style = new ColumnStyle();
        style.SizeType = SizeType.Percent;
        style.Width = (float)(1.0 / col);
        t.ColumnStyles.Add(style);
    }

    // dynamically add grid in necessary place in layout
    for(int r = 0; r<row; r++)
        for (int c = 0; c < col; c++)
        {
            grids[r,c] = new DataGridView()
                {
                    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                };
            t.Controls.Add(grids[r, c], c, r);
        }
}
```

Comment: Follow your code, but output result is strange.
Maybe choose 16 number, then output result is same 4 number output reulst.

Comment: @GeunMoLee, fixed it now :)

Comment: @GeunMoLee, any feedback?  did this code solve your issue?

Comment: Thx, problem is solved.
And, I have some question. So, to send an e-mail, if you do not mind ask me your e-mail address?

Comment: @GeunMoLee, if answer helped you, you can accept it and/or upvote (see SO tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour); if you have more questions - you are welcome ask a new question. if a question is related to my answer - post a comment, please, i will try to explain

Comment: well, here I will question.
Follow your code, 16, 25 and 36 there is no problem if the partition.
But if 2, 4 and 9 choose this number, I want to fill the Datagridview as shown in Figure questions.
2, 4 and 9 choose this split number, there is a gap between Datagridview.

Comment: @GeunMoLee, set `Dock` property of grid to `DockStyle.Fill` when create a grid (see my edit)